# PostgreSQL continuous archiving - use snapshot for base backup on AWS?

Tags: postgresql, backup, aws

I'm new to AWS and PostgreSQL admin and have been poring over the docs trying to come up with a good backup strategy for a fairly simple setup.

I have a single Amazon Web Services EC2 instance that will run a web app and a PostgreSQL 9.2.7 database. My setup is pretty similar to [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/21643/41155), but I'm considering a different approach.  Because I must encrypt the data, I'm storing it on a separate EBS volume formatted with XFS. I expect the database will be fairly small (a few GB) for a while. I want to be able to restore up with next to no data loss, so continuous archiving seems the way to go.

It looks like I can ship the WAL files directly to S3, probably using s3cmd (see [this code](https://github.com/9apps/pgRDS/blob/9f9679731acd6ad23ed3fb774aa570daa47549ff/etc/postgresql/9.1/main/postgresql.conf#L27)).

But what about base backups? The [PostgreSQL docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/continuous-archiving.html#BACKUP-BASE-BACKUP) recommend using a file-based tool like tar. I had been planning to create an EBS snapshot as the base backup using a sequence something like this:

pg_start_backup
sync
freeze XFS
create snapshot
unfreeze XFS
pg_stop_backup

The PostgreSQL docs do talk about "consistent snapshots" [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/backup-file.html), but not in conjunction with continuous archiving. Is there any reason to avoid snapshots as a way of getting a base backup?  Wouldn't restoring an EBS volume from a snapshot be faster than creating an empty EBS volume and untarring a large file? It is a bit of a management headache since the base is not stored with the WAL files...

Also, if the snapshot is the way to go, do I need the freeze/unfreeze the XFS volume? For reasons I don't understand, the continuous archiving docs actually advise against stopping database writes during a base backup:  "It is neither necessary nor desirable to stop normal operation of the database while you do this."

Comment: Use `pg_basebackup`. It's simple and easy. The docs are correct: you don't need to freeze. If you freeze, you don't need to use `pg_start_backup()` and `pg_stop_backup()` - their purpose is to allow a backup to be taken at the file system level without requiring a consistent snapshot to be taken.

Comment: Thanks @CraigRinger. I glossed over the mention of `pg_basebackup` when I read section 24.3.2. Does this mean snapshots + continuous archiving won't work, or just that snapshots are overkill if one can use `pg_base_backup` instead?

Comment: EBS snapshots are not useful if you use `pg_basebackup` or `pg_start_backup`/rsync/`pg_stop_backup`. Freezing xfs will actively stop them working because they must write a checkpoint to finish the backup. Freeze and snapshot *or* use the live backup tools. `pg_basebackup -X stream` makes it a no brainer.

Comment: If you want an easy system to work with, I would look at wal-e for shipping WAL logs to S3. Works great and is fairly easy to set up. Remember to rest a restore!

Comment: @trygvis, thanks for the tip. https://github.com/wal-e/wal-e looks pretty good but I don't see any mention of S3 Server Side Encryption or of using IAM roles for security.

Comment: **Don't use `s3cmd` ever for anything automated** The author had made a horrible mistake where the `s3cmd` returned 0 status when the DNS couldn't resolve amazon.com. [See the bug here](http://sourceforge.net/p/s3tools/bugs/96/).